# Adding two tabs to text in R string

Tags: r, text, tabs

I am replacing " o " with new line character, a carriage return and two tabs and the o. It works except I'm only getting one tab, why? How can I specify two tabs since \t\t does not work.

```
data.frame(lapply(dfClean[,selectCols], gsub, pattern = " o ", replacement = "\r\n\t\to ", perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. I have two tabs as expected. Could you share a sample input string and its output string please?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.